# SQL , most frequent occurs value

Tags: sql, frequency

I have two typical tables, Customer and Contact with one to many relationship
For instance my tables are populated like this:

```
Customer
-------------
CustomerId
    1

Contact
---------------
ContactId     CustomerId    FName      LName       Address       CreatedAt
    1             1         John       Smith       Add1         25/01/2013
    2             1         John       Cole        Add1         26/01/2013
    3             1         Alex       Cole        Add1         27/01/2013
    4             1         John       Smith       Add2         28/01/2013 
    5             1         Alex                   Add2         29/01/2013
```

I would like to create a new row out of these 5 rows with the following conditions:

For each field(column) pick the one that occurs most frequent and not null or empty.

If non occurs more than the others the newest record should be used which is not null or empty.

So for the above mentioned example the row should be like this:

```
CustomerId    FName      LName       Address 
    1         John       Smith        Add1
```

Thanks

Comment: I can write this query for you. I charge $100/hour with a minimum billed time of two hours, paid up-front. Do you have Paypal?

Comment: Show what you have tried and then we can help out...  Also, which RDBMS -- this can by DB specific...

Answer (score 2):

You didnt specify which RDBMS but I suppose this should do:

```
SELECT CustomerId, FName, LName, Address FROM Contact WHERE CustomerId = 1 GROUP BY FName, LName ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks Havenard,
I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2,
how about the second condition which is createdAt?
And also please consider it as an example that the contact table has more customerIds so the select result will be kind of one to one relationship with respect to those conditions.
Thanks again for your help

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I guess you can sort that by yourself taking the query I just gave you as model.